# How to connect an onPressed and an onTap in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have two class with differents functions :

```
    class ClassA {
onPressed: () {
    changeLocale(context, 'en');
    <---- Call OnTap from the class B --> 
 },
}



   class ClassB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassBState createState() => _ClassBState();
}

class _ClassBState extends State<ClassB> {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//with some varaible used in  function()

 GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                     function();
                  });
                },
)
...

}
```

}

I want to call the OnTap of the class B when I push onPressed from class A.

I need your help. What is the best solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: are you creating an instance of `ClassB` in `ClassA`

Comment: What do you mean ? (I'm new in development)

Comment: I mean are you doing like this in your classA: `child: ClassB()`

Comment: Yes I'm doing this to display class B, now I want to refresh class B by a Onpressed in class A

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 functions:

```
onPressed(){
  changeLocale(context, 'en');
  onTapped();
}

onTapped(){
  setState(() {  function();  });
}

class ClassA {
onPressed: onPressed,
}



   class ClassB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassBState createState() => _ClassBState();
}

class _ClassBState extends State<ClassB> {

 GestureDetector(
        onTap: onTapped ,
)
...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I have in the class B a lot of variable which are used in the function, so when I want to create onTapped outside the class B I have missing argument... But in your case I don't understand how If I push the onPressed it automatically push onTap ?

Comment: you can make your local variables inside onTapped function or another way is to make them global variable